# how to toggle label's class by clicking radio button. Vanilla JS needed instead of JQuery

Tags: javascript, onclick, radio-button

I've tried write a function in vanilla js that add class `.active` to `label` of `checked input`.
Unfortunately I stuck and I was able to write this function just using jquery.
Below is code snippet.

Important - html structure can't be changed. No additional class can be added. Inputs have to be in labels.
Any sugestion to write the same in vanilla js?
I know that I can get all `inputs` at once by `.querySelector` and use e.g `forEach` but than when click on any input, it toogle class in both `form` at once.

Thanks for help.

```js
let $fruits = $('.fruits');
let $vege = $('.vege');


const filterToggleActive = function ($filterName) {
 $inputs = $filterName.find('input');
 $inputs.each(function () {
  $(this).on('click', function () {
   $label = $filterName.find('label');
   $label.removeClass('active');
   $currentLabel = $(this).parent('label');
   $currentLabel.addClass('active');
  });
 });
}

filterToggleActive($fruits);
filterToggleActive($vege);
```

```css
.fruits {
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 15px;
}

.vege {
 border: 1px solid green;
 margin: 15px;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruits">
    <form action="">
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Apples</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Bananas</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Oranges</label>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="vege">
    <form action="">
      <label class="active"><input type="radio" name="food">Carrots</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food">Tomatos</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Potatos</label>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with just javascript. You'll want `querySelectorAll` though, as `querySelector` is the first match.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
inputs.forEach(function(i){
    i.addEventListener('click', function(el){
        var clicked = el.currentTarget;
        var active = clicked.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('.active');
        active && active.classList.remove('active');
        clicked.parentElement.classList.add('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.fruits {
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 15px;
}

.vege {
 border: 1px solid green;
 margin: 15px;
}

label {
  font-size: 18px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active {
text-decoration: underline;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fruits">
    <form action="">
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Apples</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Bananas</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Oranges</label>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="vege">
    <form action="">
      <label class="active"><input type="radio" name="food">Carrots</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food">Tomatos</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="food"> Potatos</label>
    </form>
  </div>
```